# Does IntelliJ Ultimate support the usages of wildcard when setting SQL dialects?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ has the option to specify the [SQL dialect used in a certain scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-sql-dialects.html). Is it possible to use wildcards?

Example:
`<file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/tests/*/MSSQL-tests.java" dialect="MSSQL" />`

Comment: I have added a feature request: You could up-vote it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible.

Comment: That is unfortunate, thank you for the response!